# Conversion failed on inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to inner join a smallint field on a varchar field. I only need the integer values but I am getting an error. The varchar field has integers and strings. I do not need the ID field only the DESC.

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AWOL' to data type smallint.

This is what the table look like:

```
==================================
|ID        |DESC                 |
|==========|=====================|
|ACAMPROCAL|acamprosate calcium  |
|----------|---------------------|
|BUPROPION |bupropion            |
|----------|---------------------|
|1         |Other                |
|----------|---------------------|
|4         |Expired              |
|----------|---------------------|
|3         |Dschg                |
|----------|---------------------|
|AWOL      |Absence without Leave|
==================================
```

Here is the query I've tried but also commented out:

```
SELECT 
    CASE_NUM, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MI, '' AS NA,
    DOB, SEX, [ADDRESS], '' AS NA, CITY, STATE, ZIP
    --,CONVERT(SMALLINT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(55), CDTBL1.[DESC]))
    --,CASE WHEN CDTBL1.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 99999 THEN CDTBL1.[DESC]
    --END AS COUNTY
FROM 
    CDCLIENT
INNER JOIN 
    CDTBL1 ON CDCLIENT.ADDR_COUNTY_ID = CDTBL1.ID
```

Comment: Can you do a ``cast as varchar`` on both sides of the join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
'ON CDCLIENT.ADDR_COUNTY_ID = '
```

to

```
'ON CAST(CDCLIENT.ADDR_COUNTY_ID as varchar) = '
```

You should check the datatypes of the columns you are joining on to be sure that they are the same type.
Generally I would think an ID column would be some type of int, but the table you provided above contains varchar values in the ID column as well.

There is a precedence to the datatypes in SQL and smallint is above varchar.  There is an implicit conversion taking place that is causing the failure.

More info here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with Implicit Conversions and SQL Server chose the wrong data to convert.  Typically, when you need to compare different data types, it's usually best to explicitly convert one to another.

Microsoft has a nice table on [what data types are allowed to implicitly and explicitly convert between](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_9).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want non-negative integers, then use logic like this:

```
select (case when CDTBL1.[DESC] not like '%[^0-9]%'
             then convert(smallint, CDTBL1.[DESC])
        end)
```

Note that you might also want to check the length and values of the field, to be sure you don't get an error.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can simplify this using `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(smallint, CDTBL1.[DESC])
```

This returns `NULL` if an error would occur.  But, it is not available in SQL Server 2008.